# Working with WPML and Simplepress

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, forum

I have a Danish/English WordPress 3.5.1 site with WPML and Simplepress.

My problem is that Simplepress will only show its Forum on a single Wordpress site defined with Name / Slug / page ID. And when I translate the forum page from Danish into English it will get a new Page ID.

Is there anyway I can get WordPress to just show the Danish page content (like iframing)?

I have tried this code

```
<?php
$my_id = 294;
$post_id_294 = get_post($my_id);
$content = $post_id_294->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

This will show any text that is inserted on the page, but not the forum itself.

Is there a WP command I can use to show complete page based on ID, ex: `get_page()`?